# Have problem printing source mac address in linux

Tags: c, network-programming

`etherheader` points to the header of ether packet as its name implies:

```
    printf("Source MAC address: "
           "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",
           etherheader[0],etherheader[1],etherheader[2],
           etherheader[3],etherheader[4],etherheader[5]);

struct ether_header {
    u_int8_t ether_dhost[6];
    u_int8_t ether_shost[6];
    u_int16_t ether_type;
}
```

It turns out the above code always prints:

```
Source MAC address: 40:40:8d:40:b8:f4
```

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
Destination MAC address: 40:40:8d:40:b8:f4
Source MAC address: 88:43:e1:7c:46:7f
Source host 123.126.50.73
Dest host *.*.27.*
----------
Destination MAC address: 40:40:8d:40:b8:f4
Source MAC address: 88:43:e1:7c:46:7f
Source host 114.62.80.83
Dest host *.*.27.*
```

Comment: does that correspond to the mac address for your network card?

Comment: It's printing exactly what is contained in the array you're giving it. Without code showing how you populate that array, there's not much anyone can offer.

Comment: @Foo Bah ,it's always the same for different IPs.

Comment: mac address != ip address.  read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: @Foo Bah ,why do you think I don't know that?

Comment: @lexer if your machine had one active nic (i.e. if you were using wireless on your laptop) then all internet traffic would go through that one NIC.  Since the wireless interface would have a fixed mac address, it would always be the same.  That being said, the expectation that the mac address would change even though traffic used the same network interface suggested a confusion regarding MAC addresses

Comment: @lexer: I don't think you've understood *whose* MAC address you're printing..

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis,that's the point, but after I fixed this issue, the result is still always the same for different IPs..

Comment: What's the network setup (first hop) of the box you're running the code on?

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis ,is there any command to show what you refer to?

Comment: @lexer on windows `ipconfig /all` shows you the information.  on linux/osx, `ifconfig` will show it.  Your router (next hop) probably has some interface to get the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) is a protocol (suite) for Local Area Networks. If your machine is statically connected, point-to-point, to a single router/switch which provides it with internet access, then this is where all your incoming packets originate from (the *last hop*, for your ingress traffic). This means that regardless what IP on the internet you're trying to establish IP communication with, all packets will traverse the link between your machine and your router/switch (through Ethernet).

If you are connected to a single network element, and neither your nor its network configuration changes, MAC addresses for those two machines (network cards, to be more precise) will remain the same. This behaviour seems to be what you're observing.

Comment: Do you mean that when transferring packets, source mac address may be changed at the destination side, but source ip address will NOT be changed?

Comment: I mean that the MAC address you are printing (source) is not the MAC address of the machine with the IP you specify, but the address of your router/switch, which is always the same (I assume).

Comment: So my statement is also right,true?

Comment: For the simplest case (static connection, no config changes, etc.), yes.

Answer (score 1):

If packets originate from outside the broadcast domain (AKA subnet) of the destination then the source MAC address will always be that of the router that provides the gateway into that broadcast domain. Although 40:40:8d doesn't appear to be a valid OUI (see http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt) so maybe there is just a programming error.

88:43:e1 is an OUI from Cisco, which lends some weight to the above paragraph being an explanation of why the source MAC address does not change.

Comment: Does this mean that when transferring packets, source mac address may be changed at the destination side, but source ip address will NOT be changed?

Comment: Yes, source MAC address will change on every router hop but IP address will always remain the same.